# How to navigate this carousel smooth two ways?

Tags: jquery, 3d, navigation, carousel

I have the following carousel, it navigates to the right just like I want but I can't get the same animation to the left. Anyone willing to help me crack this problem?

http://jsfiddle.net/kaisersoze/QDUea/5/

fullscreen:

http://jsfiddle.net/kaisersoze/QDUea/5/embedded/result/

```
function initCarousel() {
    var _center = {
        width: 210,
        height: 120,
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginTop: 0,
        marginRight: 10
    };
    var _left = {
        width: 178,
        height: 100,
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginTop: 9,
        marginRight: -118
    };
    var _right = {
        width: 178,
        height: 100,
        marginLeft: -119,
        marginTop: 9,
        marginRight: 0
    };
    var _outLeft = {
        width: 133,
        height: 75,
        marginLeft: 210,
        marginTop: 9,
        marginRight: -250
    };
    var _outRight = {
        width: 133,
        height: 75,
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginTop: 9,
        marginRight: 210
    };

    var i = 0;

    $('#carousel ul').carouFredSel({
        debug: true,
        width: 600,
        height: 135,
        align: false,
        auto: false,
        items: {
            visible: 5,
            width: 100
        },
        next: {
            button: '#btn-go-right',
            items: 1,
            duration: 600,
            onBefore: function(data) {

                if(i > 1){
                    i = 1;
                }

                data.items.old.eq( 0 ).animate(_outLeft);
                    data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).animate(_left).removeClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).animate(_center).addClass('active' );
                    data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).animate(_center).addClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 3 ).animate(_right).css({ zIndex: 1 }).removeClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 4 ).next().css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: 0 });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    data.items.old.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 3 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 4 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                }, 300);
            }
        },
        prev: {
            button: '#btn-go-left',
            items: 1,
            duration: 600,
            onBefore: function(data) {

                $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 4 ).css(_outRight).css({ zIndex: -1 });

                if(i < 4){
                    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 0 ).css(_left).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 4 ).css(_right).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    // $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 0 ).animate(_outLeft).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    // $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 1 ).animate(_left).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    // $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 2 ).animate(_center).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    // $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 3 ).animate(_center).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    $('#carousel ul').css({'position':'relative','left':'10px'});
                    i++;
                }

                data.items.old.eq( 0 ).animate(_center);
                    data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).animate(_left).removeClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).animate(_center).addClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).animate(_center).addClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 3 ).animate(_right).css({ zIndex: 1 }).removeClass('active');
                    data.items.visible.eq( 4 ).next().css(_outLeft).css({ zIndex: 0 });

                setTimeout(function () {
                    data.items.old.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 0 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 1 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 2 ).css({ zIndex: 3 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 3 ).css({ zIndex: 2 });
                    data.items.visible.eq( 4 ).css({ zIndex: 1 });
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 0 ).css(_left).css({ zIndex: 2 });
    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 1 ).css(_center).css({ zIndex: 3 });
    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 2 ).css(_center).css({ zIndex: 3 });
    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 3 ).css(_right).css({ zIndex: 2 });
    $('#carousel ul').children().eq( 4 ).css(_outLeft).css({ zIndex: 1 });

}


$(document).ready( function(){

initCarousel();

});
```

PS. You can navigate by clicking on the right/left item in the carousel

Comment: Please note that after clicking left five times it does animate like I want and the same as to the right. The problem only occurs the first five times clicking to the left and after clicking right on time again the first five times clicking to the left

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I was almost there. Only thing missing was the following in the prev button handler:

data.items.visible.first().css(_outLeft);